# After Calling a Flow from Apex Unable to get a Response

Tags: visual-workflow

I am calling a Flow from Apex as below. In Flow I am running a duplicate check. If there is a duplicate I am saving it into a Variable that is marked as **Available for output**. How the return value is null. Has anyone had experience with return values from Flows?

```
        Flow.Interview.Duplicate_Payee_Check DupeCheck = new Flow.Interview.Duplicate_Payee_Check (params);
    DupeCheck.start();

    // Obtain the results
    String returnValue = (String) DupeCheck.getVariableValue('ReturnValue');
    System.debug('Flow returned ' + returnValue);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to (intelligently) guess that the issue is the variable in the flow is not the same spelling/case of `ReturnValue`. For example, if the flow defines the output variable as `returnValue` the `getVariableValue('ReturnValue')` method will return null

See [SFDC doc on flow variables](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_troubleshoot_url.htm&type=5)